# Add Thousands Separator to Integer - Applescript

Tags: excel, string, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm having the craziest time trying to get a thousands separator (comma) into my numbers using Applescript. I found two subroutines on the net that supposedly will do the trick, but nothing seems to be going right.

It's giving me all sorts of random formatting. I tried changing up from integer, to real, to small integer, to string, etc. Nothing seems to help.

**What I'm passing:**

```
set perCapita2014 to avgHHinc2014 / avgPopHH2014 as integer -- results 17005
```

**The call:**

```
set finalPerCapita2014 to (comma_delimit(perCapita2014)) -- results 0.,0.5
```

**Subroutines: (apparently it requires both of these)**

```
on number_to_string(this_number)
set this_number to this_number as string
if this_number contains "E+" then
    set x to the offset of "." in this_number
    set y to the offset of "+" in this_number
    set z to the offset of "E" in this_number
    set the decimal_adjust to characters (y - (length of this_number)) thru ¬
        -1 of this_number as string as number
    if x is not 0 then
        set the first_part to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of this_number as string
    else
        set the first_part to ""
    end if
    set the second_part to characters (x + 1) thru (z - 1) of this_number as string
    set the converted_number to the first_part
    repeat with i from 1 to the decimal_adjust
        try
            set the converted_number to ¬
                the converted_number & character i of the second_part
        on error
            set the converted_number to the converted_number & "0"
        end try
    end repeat
    return the converted_number
else
    return this_number
end if
end number_to_string

on comma_delimit(this_number)
    set this_number to this_number as string
    if this_number contains "E" then set this_number to number_to_text(this_number)
    set the num_length to the length of this_number
    set the this_number to (the reverse of every character of this_number) as string
    set the new_num to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to the num_length
        if i is the num_length or (i mod 3) is not 0 then
            set the new_num to (character i of this_number & the new_num) as string
        else
            set the new_num to ("," & character i of this_number & the new_num) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return the new_num
end comma_delimit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing is to use a complicated perl call using do shell script:

```
set perCapita2014 to (avgHHinc2014 / avgPopHH2014) as integer
set finalPerCapita2014 to do shell script "echo " & perCapita2014 & " | perl -lpe'1 while s/^([-+]?\\d+)(\\d{3})/$1,$2/'"
```

Applescript is not good with text crunching like this. (I first tried to use printF, but the locale is not set for do shell script calls.)

Comment: I honestly had no idea I could use Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simpler way with PHP, because PHP has a built-in function for adding commas to numbers.

```
on comma_delimit(theNumber)
    set thePHPScript to "echo number_format(" & theNumber & ");"
    set theShellScript to "php -r" & space & quote & thePHPScript & quote
    set theNumberTextWithCommas to do shell script theShellScript
    return theNumberTextWithCommas
end comma_delimit
```

Generally speaking, you should not do any real processing in AppleScript itself, because it is not designed for that. It’s designed for messaging between apps and users — for sending input to an app or user and getting the output back and using that as input for the next app or user. The same as bash pipes, basically, but in the GUI.

So the reason AppleScript is no good at crunching text is because AppleScript is great at sending messages to apps like BBEdit or Perl to make them crunch text. And AppleScript is no good at crunching images because AppleScript is great at sending messages to apps like Photoshop or Image Events to make them crunch images. An ideal AppleScript is just a bunch of messages going back and forth between apps and the user via "tell application" blocks, "do shell script" commands, "do javascript" commands, and for the user: "display dialog" or "choose from list" or "choose file" messages.